# Jquery check for alphanumeric charactres

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code  Using jquery how to check for only alaphanumeric charaters.Even space and none of the special symbols should be allowed.I do want o use a external plugin

```
 var a='a hjdshj%^& ff234 ./.';

  if(var a has special characters)
  {
      alert('has special characters');
  }
```

`EDIT` : Even single and double quotes should not be allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of any plugin to check this

you can make use of Regular exprssion to do it easily..

try this

```
var str='a hjdshj%^& ff234 ./.';
var re = new RegExp(/\$|\/|\^|-/\s,"g");
specialchars = str.match(re);
alert(specialchars.length);
```